# NLog shows RichTextBoxTarget object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, winforms, nlog

I am seeing an exception caught by the Application.ThreadException handler. It is right around calls to either:

```
LogManager.Configuration = config
```

Or

`logger.Factory.ReconfigureExistingLoggers()`

The exception message is:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The source is NLog.Windows.Forms

The StackTrace is:

`at NLog.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxTarget.SendTheMessageToRichTextBox(String logMessage, RichTextBoxRowColoringRule rule, LogEventInfo logEvent)`

I have tried to turn on the internal logger and it seems to exacerbate issues, because some cross-thread exception will appear, pointing to the RichTextBox as being accessed illegaly.

What is the best way to debug this issue?

Comment: sow the definition of RichTextBoxTarget

Comment: Sounds like you should create an issue at https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Windows.Forms with the full callstack. Throwing `NullReferenceException` seems like a bug.